# Help creating md5 in php

Tags: php, string, md5, concatenation

I am trying to create an md5 value in php  using the instruction given. I can't seem to get it right and would like you help understanding the instructions and the code.

This is what the instructions say:

The md5 is constructed by performing an MD5 calculation on a string built up by concatenating these fields. Specifically the MD5 hash is a concatenation of the following fields:

- $user_id
- $trans_id
- the uppercase MD5 value of the ASCII 
  equivalent of the word  'secret'
- $amount
- $currency
- in $status

In order to calculate it yourself concatenate them and perform a MD5 calculation on this string.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be homework. This can be found in the Moneybookers Gateway Manual. The "instructions" aren't homework, the user is trying to follow a manual's instructions for checking a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yourMd5 = md5($user_id . $trans_id . strtoupper(md5('secret')) . $amount . $currency . $status);
```

That is what I interpreted the question as.

Of course, you could precompute the hash for the uppercase hash of `secret`. But if it's homework, probably best to show your work like above.

Answer (score 0):

`$result = md5($user_id . $trans_id . strtoupper('secret') . $amount . $currency . $status)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "in $status" but it should be something looking :

```
echo md5($user_id.$trans_id.strtoupper(md5(ord(s).ord(e).ord(c).ord(r).ord(e).ord(t))).$amount.$currency.$status);
```

Comment: I think the "ASCII equivalent" just means between characters mapping from 97 to 122. But I may be wrong.